# Finding 1st free "index" using java streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I need to find 1st free index in my file system having stream of names as source.

Consider list: ["New2", "New4", "New0", "New1", ...]
1st unused index of those will be 3.

```
int index = 0;
try (IntStream indexes = names.stream()
    .filter(name -> name.startsWith("New"))
    .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
    .distinct()
    .sorted())
{
    // I was thinking about making possible indexes stream, removing existig ones from try-with-resource block, and getting .min().
    IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 10)... // Idk what to do.
}
```

I am asking someone to help me find right syntax for my idea or propose better solution.

Comment: `Integer::parseInt` will fail unless you trim out the prefix first.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most efficient way is to collect into a `BitSet`:

```
int first = names.stream()
    .filter(name -> name.startsWith("New"))
    .mapToInt(s -> Integer.parseInt(s.substring(3)))
    .collect(BitSet::new, BitSet::set, BitSet::or).nextClearBit(0);
```

Note that the bits are intrinsically sorted and distinct. Also, there will always be a “free” index. If there is no gap between `0` and the maximum number, the next free will be maximum+1, if there are no matching elements at all, the next free will be zero.

---

Starting with Java 9, we can do even more efficient with

```java
int first = names.stream()
    .filter(name -> name.startsWith("New"))
    .mapToInt(s -> Integer.parseInt(s, 3, s.length(), 10))
    .collect(BitSet::new, BitSet::set, BitSet::or).nextClearBit(0);
```

which parses the relevant part of the string directly, saving the `substring` operation.

Comment: That is indeed very cool! +1 (and the checkmark should go to you)

Comment: I love one-liners! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You could:

1. Extract the numeric part from each name
2. Store the used indexes in a set
3. Iterate over the range from 0 until the size of the list
4. The first index not in the used set is available

For example like this:

```
List<String> names = Arrays.asList("New2", "New4", "New0", "New1");
Set<Integer> taken = names.stream()
    .map(s -> s.replaceAll("\\D+", ""))
    .map(Integer::parseInt)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
int first = IntStream.range(0, names.size())
    .filter(index -> !taken.contains(index))
    .findFirst()
    .orElse(names.size());
```

Comment: Why not use `collect(toSet())`? Alternatively, you could collect to a list and compare index to value (`.filter(i -> taken.get(i) > i)`).

Comment: Thanks @shmosel, collect to a set is better, updated.

Answer (score 0):

For the fun of it, if you *know* you have up to 63 entries...

```
    private static int firstMissing(List<Long> input) {
        if (!input.contains(0L)) {
           return 0;
        }

        long firstMissing = Long.lowestOneBit(~input.stream().reduce(1L, (i, j) -> i | 1L << j));

        int result = 0;
        while (firstMissing != 0) {
           ++result;
           firstMissing = firstMissing >> 1;
        }

        return result - 1;
    }
```

That's what @Holger did (+1 from me), but without the extra penalty of using BitSet.